# Selenium (Chrome) opens blank page and returns <html><head></head><body></body></html>

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web, w3c

if I open a website with Selenium (headless or not), a blank page gets opened and the output is:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

if I open the page manually in my browser, the website loads normal. I tried it with time.sleep(10), removed the random and I played around with different arguments like:

```
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
...
```

even reinstalling chromedriver did not help.

No success so far.

Here is my code:

```
url = "https://www.arket.com/de_de/men/knitwear/product.alpaca-blend-jumper-grey.0937502001.html"
options = Options()
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
#options.add_argument("headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver', options=options)
time.sleep(5)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.quit()

soup
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

It might be remarkable that the page sometimes loads correctly with selenium, but usually it doesnt.

yesterday the output of the code was different:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this line?
```options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')``` You don't need any of these sleep calls - by default Selenium waits to page loads fully (document.readyState = 'complete')

Comment: fake useragent helps me to act like a real user. for some websites i need to wait for the website itself, to get source code, but in this case you are right. it wont change anything. if i skip the time.sleep lines and the fake useragent as well, i still wont get the requested output...

Comment: I have tried to execute your code and get output successfully. What output did you get? blank page?

Comment: the browser window opens, but stays blank. if i execute soup, i ll get : <html><head></head><body></body></html>

Comment: It might be because the website is currently down.

Comment: i try this for a couple of days, unfortunately the website is not down. as mentioned the website works good when i manually work with the browser, but as soon as i use selenium, i usually doesnt work anymore...

Comment: I also get a down for maintenance page when accessing the products.

Comment: this is somehow weird. maybe this is due to country selection (instead of 'de_de' it could be 'en' for people outside germany)

Comment: @sebk I truly believe the problem is from the website. I've tried to get access selecting Germany as country and it throws me "Down for maintenance" message but changing to "International shipping" everything works perfect even as Selenium bot. Your code has no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. My code looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



chrome_options                    = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.headless           = True
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities = capabilities, 
                            chrome_options          = chrome_options)

driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
driver.page_source
```

The problem is neither with the website nor with the user agent as mentioned in the comments. I downgraded the selenium from 4.7.0 to 4.2.0 and it is working now. There is some issue with the latest version of selenium.

Comment: I am still unable to download.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a user agent chrome_options.add_argument(„user-agent=derry“) works for me